# Scalar product, unitary space, orthogonal projection. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $(X, \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle )$ be an inner-product space. Consider $V\subset X$ a subspace with $P_V(x)$ theh orthogonal projection of $x$ on $V$.
Then:
**a.** $x-P_V(x)$ is orthogonal projection of $x$ on subspace $V^{\perp}$.
**b.** if $P_V(P_V(x))=x$ then $x\in V$
**c.** if $v\in V$ and $||v-x|| \le ||P_v(x)-x||$ then $v=P_V(x)$.

**My approach**

**a.** We know that $x=v+w$, where $w\in V^{\perp}$ and $P_V(x)=v$.
So $x-P_v(x) = w$.   We can see that $v$ is orthogonal projection of $x$ on $V$, and analogously $w$ is orthogonal projection of $x$ on $V^{\perp}$.  Hence, **a.** is true.
**b.** I know that if $x\in V$ then $P_V(x)=x$, but I am not sure this one.
**c.** I know theorem:
$||x-P_Z(x)|| \le ||x-z||$ - moreover we have equality if only and only $z=P_Z(x)$.
Because of $||a-b||=||b-a||$ then using assumption in **c.**  we have that $||v-x||=||P_V(x)-x||$. Therefore **c.** is true.

Can you check my reasoning **a.,c.** and help with solving **b.** please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b, if $P_Vx=x$, then 
$$
x-P_V(x)=P_V(x)-P_V(x)=0. 
$$
So b follows from a.

Note that $P_VP_Vx=P_Vx$, because $P_V$ is a projection (it is the identity on its image).

Comment: If my answers for **a** and **c** are ok ?   It is true that $P_V(P_V(P_V(P_V(x)))) = P_V(x)$  ?

Comment: Why you conclude that if $P_{V^{\perp}}(x)=0$ then $x\in V$ ?

Comment: c is fine. I cannot judge a without knowing your definition of projection. Since $P_V^2=P_V$, any amount of further powers will do nothing. Finally, if $P_{V^\perp}(x)=0$, then $$ x=P_V(x)+P_{V^\perp}(X)=P_V(x).$$